# Cannot resolve constructor (Android Intent)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a simple button that opens to a different activity:

```
package com.example.xxx.buttonexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnClick();
}
public void btnClick() {
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,emergencyIntent.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here is my emergencyIntent.class file:

```
package com.example.xxx.buttonexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class emergencyIntent extends Activity
{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // The activity is being created.

}

}
```

I received a error:

> "Cannot resolve constructor 'intent(anonymous
>   android.view.View.OnClickListener,
>   java.lang.Class(com.example.xxx.buttonexample.emergencyIntent))'.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Just replace `this` in first parameter with `MainActivity.this`. like:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,emergencyIntent.class);
```

The error is because you are writing it in `public void onClick(View v)`, where '`this`' will mean instance of anonymous class that implements `View.OnClickListener`. while first parameter in Intent constructor `Intent(Context context, Class<?> cls)` requires Activity context.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.example.xxx.buttonexample;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new  Intent(MainActivity.this,emergencyIntent.class);
startActivity(intent);
//Or Intent intent = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),emergencyIntent.class);

            }
        });
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

package com.example.xxx.buttonexample;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button button;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new  Intent(MainActivity.this,emergencyIntent.class);
```

startActivity(intent);
//Or Intent intent = new  Intent(getApplicationContext(),emergencyIntent.class);

```
        }
```

});## Heading ##